Python server that simulates an ML training process with Flask and SocketIO (issues with multithreading & multiprocessing)
I am trying to create a client-server app in which the client can send a HTTP request with files to the server to start a process of training an AI model. I want the client to be able to get updates about the progress.
There are some issues though.
See the process of training just as a function (model.train(...)) which takes a very long time. So I would have to run it on another thread / process.
The problem with running it on another thread is that, I cannot force stop this specific thread if a HTTP request comes from the client to stop it.
If I use multiprocessing, and just run it on a new process, I can solve this issue.
But a new problem arises, and that is now I can't constantly send updates to the client, because the training just runs on another process, and I can't use the starting socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*").
How would I solve this? I can only update the client from the main process. Do I have to create a thread for both processes so that the thread from the second process sends information to the thread of first process?
I am not uploading any code since it's pretty pointless and complicated, I just explained through which kind of issues I got. I kind of need a plan of organizing this.

maybe you should use Celery to run processes. It should give ID for this process and you can create other page to check this ID and display information if result is ready..

Background Tasks with Celery — Flask Documentation (2.3.x)
